# CocoaPods: How are "fixes" in the pod sources handled for update?

Tags: git, cocoapods

I just started using CocoaPods and there's something that's not completely clear to me.

As far as I understand, the `pod` command line utility fetches the PodSpecs from https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs

`pod install` looks up these specs and clones the corresponding repositories from the local *Podfile* (like on github or else).

`pod update` fetches the specs again and checks for updates. If there is a new version that matches the local *Podfile*, these updates are fetched.

Now I noticed some projects that have a podspec who update their repository without increasing their version number in their podspec.

That would mean that if I install a pod at time A and somebody installs the same version at time B, they would get different sources.

Also, if the first person would do an update at time B, they wouldn't get the updates, since pod assumes that there is no new version. Is this correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things here that I want to respond to.

> Now I noticed some projects that have a podspec who update their repository without increasing their version number in their podspec.

This should not typically be an issue. While people may be updating their repo without updating their podspecs, we enforce that all podspecs (with one exception) be based on git tags. Because of this unless the library owner deleted and remade the tag at a new position (which could be done) the source *should* never change based on the corresponding podspec. The single exception to this is specs marked version `0.0.1` (although not all specs of that version do this). Those specs we allow to be 'unversioned' meaning they can point to a single git commit in the repo. While we don't allow the updating of this commit either we think of that as being more malleable since it could break easily with something like a rebase. We also think that if a library author isn't willing to tag a repo we shouldn't treat it as if it's being maintained.

I think this indirectly answers the question about installing at different times. The answer *should* be that both users would get the same source.

If you are worried about not getting the correct versions (although this is also managed by the Podfile.lock) you can include pods like this:

```
pod 'foo', '1.0'
```

Which will force the install of 1.0 always. You can also use the semantic version matcher with this:

```
pod 'foo', '~> 1.0.0'
```

This will also give you updated versions that *should* not break compatibility. Note that the version numbers are not required to be semantic so it's really up to the library owner's discretion.

Finally running `pod update` will compare the numbers in the Podfile.lock with your Podfile and grab the highest new version that satisfies your constraints. This is especially useful if you're not specifying a version at all like:

```
pod 'foo'
```

So that will always update to the newest podspec for the library (if it isn't there already).

**Edit:**

To clarify about updates. If someone fixes the source of their repo and wants that to carry over to their CocoaPod they **have** to submit a **new** version of the spec. We do not allow the updating of the source location in **any** existing specs. Either way CocoaPods will install the version saved in the Podfile.lock. If there is a new version you want you have to run `pod update`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I knew about these version numbers in the Podfile. So if I understand you correct, "fixes" in the git repository will be ignored by pods until somebody updates the tag? but even then, pods wouldn't recognize an update since the podspec version did not change, so you will only get the updates when you install, not on update (?)

Comment: Thanks again, one more thing to clarify: You say you do "not allow" updating the source in an existing spec. But there is no specific commit hash in the specs, so if the owner of a repo just updates the source and the tags, how can pods tell that this is an "invalid" update? Wouldn't any new pod install fetch the "new" source with the same version number?

Comment: If the library author retagged the library we do not have any insight into that. There is a hash in the Podfile.lock based off the spec. If the spec changes that will change. So when you do an install and there is a new source (if you don't already have it installed) it will get the new source.